# What is a $\lambda$-Polish Space?

Tags: general-topology

I was reading the [description of a course on "Generalized Descriptive Set Theory"](http://torino.logicgroup.altervista.org/torino/courses.php) and they list as the singular case of generalized Baire and Cantor spaces what they call $\lambda$-Polish space. After an intense googling session, I could not find anything about this entity. Have you ever encountered it? I am aware of the general properties of Polish spaces, by the way, and I do know that Baire and Cantor spaces are also Polish spaces.

Comment: Using the author's name, the top hit of [my first google search attempt](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Motto+Ros%22+%22Polish+space%22) was [these slides](http://www.math.helsinki.fi/logic/arctic/2019/Slides/Dimonte.pdf), which discusses this (and other similar) notions.

Comment: Thanks, I must have really missed it. The question is considered closed.